# Home button randomly closes activity

Tags: java, android, google-maps, location, maps

What should I do to prevent activity from being destroyed when home button is pressed. My activity is destroyed by pressing home Randomly.

Thanks in advance

Comment: we didn't understand the question !

Comment: I am trying to correct my English.. But why down vote Question?

Comment: one of the reason is that "destroy activities" option is turned on in your device(Samsung S3) developer settings

Comment: i didn't down voted lol,

Answer (score 1):

This is the activity lifecycle-
When any application's activity goes to the background after the Home button was pressed, it isn't destroyed arbitrarily - the OS destroys activities in the background when it runs short of available RAM, so when the Home button is pressed the activity goes to onPause() -> onStop() and then it's up to the OS's mercy.
[image: Activity Lifecycle]

This can happen to any device running Android OS which runs into a low memory scenario at any given time, not only Galaxy S3.

The way to handle this is to use onSaveInstanceState in your activity:

```
    @Override
    protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        // Put all important data you have into the outState before calling
        // super.
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle state) {
        super.onRestoreInstanceState(state);
    // Here you will receive the bundle you put in onSaveInstanceState
    // and you can take it from the state bundle and put it in place.
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            // Here you need to check if you have data, if 
            // onSaveInstanceState was called and you put data in that 
            // function, data should be available here, and put it back into 
            // place.
        }
```

Comment: Thank you so much for such a detailed answer. @Matan